# Wordpress: Sign in with HTML, Javascript, and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just want the most effecient way to have a member page with a reset password function.

I can't use PHP or plugins like forminator because I am using wordpress for free. I can only use HTML, Javascript, and CSS.

HTML

```
    <html>
<head>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body id="body">
    <h1>    </h1>
        <div>
            <form>
                <div>
                    <label for="Uname" class="signInLabel">Username</label>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <input type="text" name="Uname" placeholder="Enter Username" id="username" class="signInInput" required/>
                </div>
                 <br>
                 <br>
                 <br>
                <div>
                    <label for="Pword" class="signInLabel">Password</label>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <input type="password" name="Pword" placeholder="Enter Password" id="password" class="singInInput" required/>
                </div>
                    <br>
                    <button id="signInSubmit" onclick="verify()">Sign-In</button>
            </form>
            <p id="incorrect Password"></p>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //Sign In Verifacation
            function verify () {
                var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
                var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
                var Admin {
                    FirstName: "Admin",
                    LastName: "1010",
                    Fullname: this.FirstName + this.LastName,
                    Greeting: "Welcome Back" + this.Fullname,
                id: 00001,
                    Username: "Admin",
                    Password: "1010",
                }
                //Put the members here
                
                if (username == Admin.Username && password == Admin.Password) {
                    
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('incorrect Password').innerHTML = "Incorrect Password";
                }
            }
        </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! The reset password function would require some interaction with the backend. Maybe you can share more details about your theme and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

To communicate to Wordpress you **will** need to make use of either the wordpress hooks within the functions.php or make use of the [wp_signon()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_signon/)

I can help you out but you need to be willing to make a PHP file, since that is the only way to make it happen.

If you do userlogin by front-end (unless you are using NodeJS or REACT which make use of json files), you will be in for a lot of trouble.

Please make it a habbit to never directly accept user input from the client side (the person browsing your website).

What you can do is have a form within index.php and then redirect to your login.php file on submit (send form) and [sanitize](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-are-the-best-input-sanitizing-functions-in-php/) all user input before you pass that data to the WordPress function's -> wp_signon().

By using Xamp or Mamp, a quick dive into PHP: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZdP0KM49IVk

This website is very good to start using PHP and then move on to more: https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-php

Please do share what your next move will be.

Comment: well I have the verifacation built in so it all works I just need a way to hide the form and dispaly a member sweet (I can code the member sweet I just need a way to hide the form

Answer (score 0):

Alright then, as you have asked how to "hide the form": wpmudev.com/blog/customize-login-page

And to show logged in user you would still need PHP because that data has to come from the SQLi/Wordpress Database:

If you're using a custom Wordpress Theme (made by yourself): be sure to include:

```
require_once 'wp-load.php';
```

And if it's a normal Wordpress installation then you won't need to **also** include this on top of your page

```
require_once 'wp-includes/pluggable.php';
```

I reccomend you to read out the function to see what more this Object has to give you:

```
var_dump( wp_get_current_user());
```

but to actually summon a username:

```
echo wp_get_current_user()->user_login;
```

But, that would open up a possible security breach since you're exposing their actual username. Once a malicious person find that out, he's once step closer. So instead show the user's 'nice name', which the client themselves can edit to show as a public name, that's why I sugested you check out the var_dump(), in any case:

```
echo wp_get_current_user()->user_nicename;
```

To reset the password check out Wordpress's dev guide:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/reset_password/

And if you don't succeed after reading the dev website, then please share what you have [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: if you do succeed, please share that as well.

Comment: What is the status? Have you resolved the issue, if yes how and if not then please share what went wrong. I've spend my time trying to help you out so it's not to much to ask for an update.

Comment: Please respond or close this thread.